# How to set proxy in docker toolbox?

Tags: windows, proxy, docker-toolbox

I have just installed docker toolbox on windows environnement (Windows 7 Pro) and I have got a network time out due to the entreprise proxy. How can I set the proxy in docker toolbox ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 26):

I encountered the same problem. Here is my solution.

**Env:**

Win7, Docker Toolbox 17.03, cmder terminal, behind enterprise proxy setting.

**Solution:**

in C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox, find start.sh file. add following two proxy settings:

```
export http_proxy="http://hostname:port/"
export https_proxy="http://hostname:port/"
```

At least, it works for me.

Comment: It worked for me as well, thanks :).

Just to add a bit more information, if you have to provision a user and a password to your proxy you should provide them in the following manner:


`#!/bin/bash
export http_proxy="http://[user]:[password]@hostname:port/"
export https_proxy="http://[user]:[password]@hostname:port/"`

Comment: Thankyou. I added `export http_proxy="http://hostname:port/"
export https_proxy="http://hostname:port/"` after the first `trap ...` command in the `start.sh` file.

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar problem for **Windows 7** but it was resolved by these steps :

- Step 1. Create a batch script C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\kitematic_proxy.cmd with below configuration

  ```
  set proxy=YOUR_PROXY
  SET HTTP_PROXY=%proxy%
  SET HTTPS_PROXY=%proxy% 
  for /f %%i in ('docker-machine.exe ip default') do set DOCKER_HOST=%%i
  SET NO_PROXY=%DOCKER_HOST%
  set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://%DOCKER_HOST%:2376
  cd Kitematic
  Kitematic.exe
  ```
- Step 2. Open Oracle Virtual machine from the start menu , go to command prompt by clicking **Show** (Make sure your Oracle Vm is up and running)

[image]

enter
      **sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile**

add this lines

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://your.proxy.name:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://your.proxy.name:8080
```

use your proxy address & port

this link help me a lot
https://github.com/docker/kitematic/wiki/Common-Proxy-Issues-&-Fixes

Note:

1. Don't forget to add 192.168.99.100 ip to your proxy setting's exception list (use **inetcpl.cpl** )
2. Don't forget to add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to your **user variable** (Advance settings->Environment variables)
3. Don't forget to restart your pc

Answer (score 3):

Installing docker on **windows 7** (docker 18.09.0) behind an enterprise proxy was quite complicated for me. Here are the steps I followed:

1. set HTTP_PROXY variable in your windows environment (HTTP_PROXY=http://your_proxy:port)
2. install docker toolbox with installer or run in powershell as admin: `choco install docker-toolbox` (Warning! Don't use Docker for windows, as it targets Windows 10)
3. ensure you don't have any previous VM created by your previous attempts ( `docker-machine ls` should be empty. If not run: `docker-machine rm default`)
4. run in powershell as user: `docker-machine --native-ssh create -d virtualbox --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY default`.
5. run `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh`
6. Now run `docker pull busybox`. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue on my Windows 7 Docker toolbox installation

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4eee

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build  1110ad01
```

When I tried

```
docker run hello-world
```

I received

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
>   C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while waiting headers).
>   See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

According to https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/ I've registered my enterprise proxy in `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` inside the docker machine:

> 1. Use `ssh` to log in to the virtual machine. This example logs in to the `default` machine.
>
>    ```
>    $ docker-machine ssh default
>    docker@default:~$ sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
>    ```

Then I added my enterprise proxy in the end of the `profile`

```
export "HTTP_PROXY=http://host:port"
export "HTTPS_PROXY=http://host:port"
```

after that I continued the instructions

> 2. Add a `NO_PROXY` setting to the end of the file similar to the example below.
>
>    ```
>      export "NO_PROXY=192.168.*.*"
>    ```
> 3. Restart Docker.
>      After you modify the `profile` on your VM, restart Docker and log out of the machine.
>
>    ```
>      docker@default:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
>      docker@default:~$ exit
>    ```

After that `docker run hello-world` command works well

```
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
$ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

## Configuration lost after PC restart

As @rsb2097 mentioned after every PC reboot Docker Machine lose the settings in `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`. I face the same problem too and I don't know how to avoid this, but I made a script to write these settings simpler.

I thought that happens because I shut down the PC without stopping the docker machine (VirtualBox says that there are active connections on shut down): supposed that it damages. 
I tried `docker-machine stop` but it doesn't help.

As a result I wrote `AddDockerMachineProxy.cmd` script that writes the proxy settings using `plink.exe` from Putty (https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

**Usage**

1. Restart the PC.
2. Run `Docker Quickstart Terminal`, I have following output:

   ```
   Starting "default"...
   (default) Check network to re-create if needed...
   (default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. 
   Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
   (default) Waiting for an IP...
   Machine "default" was started.
   Waiting for SSH to be available...
   Detecting the provisioner...
   Started machines may have new IP addresses. 
   You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
   Regenerate TLS machine certs?  
   Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
   Waiting for SSH to be available...
   Detecting the provisioner...
   Copying certs to the local machine directory...
   Copying certs to the remote machine...
   Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
   ```
3. Run `AddDockerMachineProxy.cmd` script (`plink.exe` must be in `%PATH%`):

   ```
   @echo off

   echo Was "Docker Quickstart Terminal" run after the reboot to init the machine?
   echo If not this script fails.
   pause

   set "exePlink=plink.exe"
   set "connectionString=-pw tcuser docker@192.168.99.100"

   echo Profile BEFORE:
   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% cat /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   echo APPENDING PROXY
   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% sudo bash -c "'echo export \"HTTP_PROXY=http://host:port\">> /var/lib/boot2docker/profile'"
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% sudo bash -c "'echo export \"HTTPS_PROXY=http://host:port\">> /var/lib/boot2docker/profile'"
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% sudo bash -c "'echo export \"NO_PROXY=192.168.*.*\">> /var/lib/boot2docker/profile'"
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   echo Profile AFTER:
   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% cat /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   echo Restart docker service:
   call "%exePlink%" %connectionString% sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
   if errorlevel 1 ( echo ERROR: PSCP failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   echo Testing connection
   call docker image pull hello-world || ( echo ERROR: docker image pull is failed !!! & goto BadExit )

   echo Done!
   exit /b 0

   :BadExit
   echo ERROR !!!
   exit /b 1
   ```

Comment: It works for me, but configuration is lost after I restart my PC.

Comment: @rsb2097, yes, I'm losing the configuration after every PC restart too. I thought that's because I shut down the PC without stopping the docker machine (VirtualBox says that there are active connections on shut down). I tried `docker-machine stop` but it doesn't help.
As a result I wrote `.cmd`-script that writes the proxy settings using `plink.exe` from Putty (https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html). I will add my script in the answer.

Comment: It works for me too but I had to change the shell from `bash` to `sh`

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Actually with Docker Toolbox windows part is just very thin layer over created virtual machine, so my method is to configure virtual machine itself to make everything work. So.

0) Set global environment variables on Windows host machine

```
HTTP_PROXY = "http://login:password@yourproxy:8080"
HTTPS_PROXY = "http://login:password@yourproxy:8080"
```

Note caps letters! (also you can set `FTP_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY`)

1) Run Docker Quickstart Terminal, it will create virtual machine named `default` under you VirtualBox or whatever. Also it will display address of your newly created VM like

`docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.104`

2) SSH to this address (i.e. with PuTTY). Login:`docker` Password:`tcuser`

3) Run

```
echo '
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://login:password@yourproxy:8080",
     "httpsProxy": "http://login:password@yourproxy:8080"
   }
 }
}' > /home/docker/.docker/config.json
```

This will force docker client (on VM!) to run containers with correct envs inside.

4) So now you can use docker client inside VM. To force Windows docker client (as well as docker-compose) also to set correct envs inside running containers, put the same `config.json` as in p.3 on Windows host machine to `C:\User\<yourhomedir>\.docker` directory.

Now check the environment inside running container

`docker run -ti ubuntu env`

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://login:password@yourproxy:8080
https_proxy=http://login:password@yourproxy:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://login:password@yourproxy:8080
http_proxy=http://login:password@yourproxy:8080
```

Note both CAPS and lower letter variables are set properly!

Final check for everything is ok:

`docker run -ti ubuntu apt-get update`

5) One issue you may face, is that address of your proxy is from network, which docker use when creating own networks, so it will spoil route to your proxy right after you will do `docker network create`. So make sure the proxy address is not like 172.18.x.x . If so force docker to use another address space for created networks by making another config on VM

```
sudo -i
echo '
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base":"172.80.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Then restart dockerd `/etc/init.d/docker restart`

6) Do not restart your virtual machine, pause it when needed.